# Duplicate class in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and I was previewing my app using usb but the following error occured . I researched a bit and when I went to my build.gradle , there was only this code present. How do I resolve it?

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}
```

I tried to follow tutorials on Youtube but it didn't worked

Comment: Include the error that was displayed. There are two build.gradle files